# How to convert the following into a standard time format in j query (2015-08-21T12:35:01.5588081Z)?

Tags: jquery, html

Actually I having a time and date format as following `2015-08-21T12:35:01.5588081Z` now what I need is how to convert this format `2015-08-21T12:35:01.5588081Z` to this one`12:35 08/21/15` in jquery. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The jQuery library isn't intended for date/time manipulation, or string manipulation. You could do this in [Vanilla JS](http://vanilla-js.com/) with a single regex-based string `.replace()`.

Comment: @nnnnnn is to possible to do in the Java script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try utilizing `new Date()` with argument `"2015-08-21T12:35:01.5588081Z"` to convert to `Date` object , `.getUTCHours()` , `.getMinutes()` , `.getDate()` , `.getDay()` , `.getFullYear()` , `String.prototype.slice()`

```js
var date = "2015-08-21T12:35:01.5588081Z";
var d = new Date(date);
var res = String(d.getUTCHours() + ":" + d.getUTCMinutes() + " ")
          .concat(d.getMonth() + 1 + "/")
          .concat(d.getDate() + "/")
          .concat(d.getFullYear().toString().slice(-2));
document.write(res);
```

Comment: iam getting the output this one 12:5 8/21/15  why the time is 12:35 but it is comming only 5

Comment: @kiran Try substituting `d.getUTCMinutes()` for `d.getMinutes()` . Can create jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate ?

Answer (score 0):

Use this jQuery plugin. You will get any kind of date format

https://github.com/phstc/jquery-dateFormat

Usage

```
<script>
  document.write($.format.date("2009-12-18 10:54:50.546", "Test: dd/MM/yyyy"));
  document.write($.format.date("Wed Jan 13 10:43:41 CET 2010", "dd~MM~yyyy"));
</script>
```

Output

> - Test: 18/12/2009
> - 18~12~2009

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use [momentjs](http://momentjs.com)

```
var str = moment('2015-08-21T12:35:01.5588081Z').format('HH:MMa MM/DD/YYYY');
console.log(str);

//05:08am 08/21/2015
```